# Add defer attribute to javascript_include_tag Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, deferred-execution

Is there some way to add the `defer` attribute easily using the `javascript_include_tag` helper in Rails?

I.e., is there some easy way to turn

`<%= javascript_include_tag "blah.js" %>`

into

`<script defer src="blah.js"></script>`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "blah.js", :defer => "defer" %>
```

This will get you (in development):

```
<script defer="defer" src="/assets/blah.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: For those interested, here is the link to the docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT

Comment: This also works great with middleman which also uses sprokets / asset pipeline.

Comment: Strange, they don't have any example of async and difer in APIDoc :\

Comment: A bit simpler, same result: <%= javascript_include_tag "blah.js", defer: true %>

Answer (score 35):

You can also do

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "blah.js", defer: true %>
```

which is more consistent with other switches.