# Am I supposed to use strings, symbols, or whatever the third thing is for include attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Take a look at these two lines:

```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', :defer => "defer" %>
```

That is generated by default in a new rails project, except for the `:defer` part, which I included to defer my scripts based on the method advised by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982375/add-defer-attribute-to-javascript-include-tag-rails).

Note that `media` is neither a symbol or a string, while `:defer` is a symbol and `'data-turbolinks-track'` is a string. I don't even know what terminology to use here so I'm calling them "include attributes," since they are the names of attributes on an include in my `application.html.erb`.

Why are there different types here? Which is suggested? Why do all three work? I find this frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything after `application` is actually a hash with symbol keys. In general,

```
{foo: 'bar'}
```

is equivalent to

```
{:foo => 'bar'}
```

When you have a string that has spaces, hyphens, etc., you need to enclose it in quotes before adding the colon; that's what's going on with `'data-turbolinks-track':`.

Finally, when passing arguments to a method, you can leave out the curly braces on the outside of the hash as long as it's unambiguous. This is often called a bare hash.

So, your calls are actually equivalent to:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', {:media => 'all', :'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload'} %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', {:'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload', :defer => "defer"} %>
```

As for which syntax to use, it's mostly a question of style and readability unless you're using older versions of Ruby (before Ruby 1.9, the "rocket" syntax using `=>` was the only option).